# Gradient Descent in Python for n Features? Part of Andrew Ng's Course

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I'm currently trying to implement gradient descent in Python 3.8, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my code to take n amount of features. I haven't been programming that long so I am not super familiar with numpy and pandas, so that's why my code is very loop-y. I'm not concerned about runtimes or fast convergence, but I would like a pointer on how to get GD to work for n variables.

I've tried initializing a list of thetas in PartialDerCal() to be passed into the GDA() function. I'm guessing I need an 'if' statement somewhere in the PartialDerCal() function, but I can't quite figure it out. Here is my stable version that works with 1 feature variable.

```
import pandas as pd #use pandas for loading and manipulating data
import numpy as np #use numpy for working with arrays
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #use matplotlib for ploting

#loading data
def LoadData():
    #reading inputs and outputs from a text file
    data = pd.read_csv("data1.txt", header=None)
    return data

#calculate partial derivative
def PartialDerCal(theta_0,theta_1, data):      
    sum_theta_0 = 0
    sum_theta_1 = 0
    
    for index, row in data.iterrows(): #row[0]=x, row[1]=y
        h_theta_x = theta_0 + theta_1 * row[0]
        sum_theta_0 = sum_theta_0 + (h_theta_x - row[1])
        sum_theta_1 = sum_theta_1 + ((h_theta_x - row[1]) * row[0])
    return sum_theta_0, sum_theta_1

def CostCal(theta_0,theta_1, data, m):
    cost = 0
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        h_theta_x = theta_0 + theta_1 * row[0]
        cost += ((1/(2*m)) * ((h_theta_x - row[1]) * ((h_theta_x) - row[1])))
    return cost
    
def GDA(data):
    
    convergence = 20
    convergence_iter = 0
    
    m = 97 #total points
    
    theta_0 = 0
    theta_1 = 0
    alpha = 0.01 
    
    theta_0s = []
    theta_1s = []
    costs = []
    
    theta_0s.append(theta_0)
    theta_1s.append(theta_1)
    temp_theta_0, temp_theta_1 = PartialDerCal(theta_0, theta_1, data)
    costs.append(CostCal(theta_0, theta_1, data, m))   
    
    while (convergence_iter < convergence):
        
        temp_theta_0 = theta_0 - (alpha * (1/m) * temp_theta_0)
        temp_theta_1 = theta_1 - (alpha * (1/m) * temp_theta_1)
        theta_0 = temp_theta_0
        theta_1 = temp_theta_1
        
        #Plot(theta_0, theta_1, data)
        theta_0s.append(theta_0)
        theta_1s.append(theta_1)
        temp_theta_0, temp_theta_1 = PartialDerCal(theta_0, theta_1, data)
        costs.append(CostCal(theta_0, theta_1, data, m))
        convergence_iter += 1
   
data = LoadData()
GDA(data)
```

data1.txt:

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
7.4764,4.3483
8.5781,12
6.4862,6.5987
5.0546,3.8166
5.7107,3.2522
14.164,15.505
5.734,3.1551
8.4084,7.2258
5.6407,0.71618
5.3794,3.5129
6.3654,5.3048
5.1301,0.56077
6.4296,3.6518
7.0708,5.3893
6.1891,3.1386
20.27,21.767
5.4901,4.263
6.3261,5.1875
5.5649,3.0825
18.945,22.638
12.828,13.501
10.957,7.0467
13.176,14.692
22.203,24.147
5.2524,-1.22
6.5894,5.9966
9.2482,12.134
5.8918,1.8495
8.2111,6.5426
7.9334,4.5623
8.0959,4.1164
5.6063,3.3928
12.836,10.117
6.3534,5.4974
5.4069,0.55657
6.8825,3.9115
11.708,5.3854
5.7737,2.4406
7.8247,6.7318
7.0931,1.0463
5.0702,5.1337
5.8014,1.844
11.7,8.0043
5.5416,1.0179
7.5402,6.7504
5.3077,1.8396
7.4239,4.2885
7.6031,4.9981
6.3328,1.4233
6.3589,-1.4211
6.2742,2.4756
5.6397,4.6042
9.3102,3.9624
9.4536,5.4141
8.8254,5.1694
5.1793,-0.74279
21.279,17.929
14.908,12.054
18.959,17.054
7.2182,4.8852
8.2951,5.7442
10.236,7.7754
5.4994,1.0173
20.341,20.992
10.136,6.6799
7.3345,4.0259
6.0062,1.2784
7.2259,3.3411
5.0269,-2.6807
6.5479,0.29678
7.5386,3.8845
5.0365,5.7014
10.274,6.7526
5.1077,2.0576
5.7292,0.47953
5.1884,0.20421
6.3557,0.67861
9.7687,7.5435
6.5159,5.3436
8.5172,4.2415
9.1802,6.7981
6.002,0.92695
5.5204,0.152
5.0594,2.8214
5.7077,1.8451
7.6366,4.2959
5.8707,7.2029
5.3054,1.9869
8.2934,0.14454
13.394,9.0551
5.4369,0.61705
```

data2.txt:

```
0.223753616,0.201342282,0.249946951
0.170154841,0.201342282,0.206195297
0.255232261,0.201342282,0.230633721
0.150587034,0.134228188,0.145005483
0.319040327,0.268456376,0.33745026
0.211098349,0.268456376,0.187444588
0.163135954,0.201342282,0.196819942
0.151756849,0.201342282,0.124379078
0.14675855,0.201342282,0.13250501
0.158882083,0.201342282,0.151568231
0.206312745,0.268456376,0.150005047
0.212693551,0.201342282,0.216883201
0.200995406,0.201342282,0.206257174
0.476220861,0.33557047,0.437454041
0.134847711,0.201342282,0.162443642
0.244597584,0.268456376,0.281198133
0.140377744,0.134228188,0.187444588
0.131444615,0.201342282,0.124942224
0.277458737,0.268456376,0.312510567
0.322337077,0.268456376,0.374389157
0.187914752,0.201342282,0.158068477
0.200782712,0.134228188,0.159381027
0.170580228,0.201342282,0.151818241
0.208652374,0.268456376,0.162443642
0.413688957,0.201342282,0.358701063
0.116981453,0.201342282,0.156193406
0.155053599,0.201342282,0.290323478
0.268631955,0.201342282,0.293136084
0.233962906,0.201342282,0.296886226
0.280436447,0.201342282,0.187444588
0.19557172,0.134228188,0.218695769
0.106346776,0.067114094,0.106191515
0.216947422,0.268456376,0.196819942
0.333609835,0.201342282,0.362451205
0.192594011,0.268456376,0.178694257
0.152820316,0.201342282,0.156193406
0.131763655,0.201342282,0.143692933
0.226731326,0.268456376,0.215633154
0.448251659,0.268456376,0.343137975
0.229921729,0.268456376,0.179381783
0.176961035,0.134228188,0.230321209
0.238004084,0.201342282,0.206195297
0.272992173,0.268456376,0.196257421
0.127616131,0.201342282,0.186882066
0.090607453,0.134228188,0.112441752
0.196954228,0.268456376,0.187444588
0.127935171,0.201342282,0.14969316
```

Comment: can you post code to generate or text to represent `data1.txt`?

Comment: Data1 is 1 input variable, 1 output variable, while data2 has 2 input variables. https://filebin.net/ew31tl1py9zubp0g

Comment: Your code works fine for me with both datasets. What exactly is the issue? Try printing out the cost at each iteration (in your case you could do `print(costs[-1])` since you made a list) and you'll be able to see the cost decreasing.